# get the data from jtextfield among a group of textfield which may or may not have data

Tags: java, swing, textfield

i want to take the printout of a survey form,in which some fields are fiiled and others are left blank.
how to take the datas of filled fields only ,in java swing.
how to check the field is empty or not.please help me.am new to java swing

Comment: `JTextField#getText`, then check to see if the `String#isEmpty` empty or not...I fail to see the problem...

Comment: You might consider taking a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for starters...

Comment: Use condition `textField.getText() != null && !textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()`